# Парсер не находит элементы на странице

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Наткнулся на канал на ютубе на видео с созданием парсера (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtizH9w0V7c&t=293s). Скопировал код по инструкции, однако при его исполнении список статей с сайта не выводится. Прошу подсказать в чем проблема.

Код

```
import requests
import bs4

r = requests.get("https://stopgame.ru/review/new/izumitelno/p1")
html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select(".item > .article-summary"):
    title = el.select('.caption > a')
    print(title[0].text)
```

Результат

> C:\Users\Computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Учеба/python_work/parsing.py
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в селекторах не силён, поэтому не знаю почему, но вот с таким селектором работает, если убрать `>`:

```
for el in html.select(".item.article-summary"):
```

Вывод:

```
Wildermyth: Обзор
Chicory: A Colorful Tale: Обзор
Griftlands: Обзор
Astalon: Tears of the Earth: Обзор
Lacuna: Обзор
The Legend of Heroes: Trails of Cold Steel 4: Обзор
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!